# Smoothing a pgfplot curve

Tags: pgfplots, plot, smooth

I am trying to generate plots with smooth curves using the `pgfplots` package.
Setting the smooth option in the `\addplot` command does not seem to make any change.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b
1,4
2,5
3,1
4,3
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [smooth, x=a, y=b, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plot of a jagged curve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `smooth` parameter should be given to the `\addplot` macro:

You may also try to change the tension parameter to a maybe higher value than the default of 0.55:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b
1,4
2,5
3,1
4,3
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[smooth,tension=0.8] table [x=a, y=b, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Or if you want to keep the color and markers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b
1,4
2,5
3,1
4,3
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[smooth,blue,mark=*] table [x=a, y=b, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

**Edit**
For your actual data you could try something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\usepackage[gobble=auto]{pythontex}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{pycode}
from numpy import *
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep=',')

x = data.x
y = data.y
## See https://stackoverflow.com/q/20618804/406686
yhat = savgol_filter(y, 51, 3) # window size 51, polynomial order 3

xyhat = list(zip(x,yhat))
savetxt('dataSmooth.csv',xyhat,fmt='%0.5f')
\end{pycode}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[smooth] table {dataSmooth.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[smooth] table [col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the smoothing doesnt seem to work for my actual data [csv pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KAeTFaBH). Are ~4000 points to many or do I have to find the right tension parameter?

Comment: @svenkal: I see, maybe you could ask this as a new (follow up) question (and if you want accept the existing answer to this one).

Comment: Maybe you could look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20642478/406686 You could for example apply this filter to the data using python and pythontex and then plot via pgfplots. If have more time later I will try it...

Comment: Sorry I forgot about the stackexchange etiquette. Thanks for the link, ill trying smoothing the data outside of LaTex.